# Error al intentar obtener el id de una tabla php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy trabado con parte de mi código porque intento obtener el id, de una de las tablas de mi base de datos, que es donde están almacenado los usuarios.

Este es el código php.

```
  if($pdo) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt = $pdo->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($idd  =$arr) {
      $id = $idd['id'];
    }
    
  }
```

Aquí abajo de la condición tengo esto:

```
echo $id;
```

$pdo es la variable de la conexión a la base de datos:

```
$pdo = new PDO($link, $usuario, $pass)
```

Pero al mostrarlo la página me salta este error:

```
fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCurso\phpyMySQL\form-sesion\profile.php:83 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpCurso\phpyMySQL\form-sesion\profile.php on line 83
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Según esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059293/2553194 el problema es que bindParam no está en ese objeto sino en PDOStatement, es decir tu $stmt. A priori bastaría con que cambiaras '$stmt = $pdo->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);' por '$stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);'

Answer (score 1):

En tu código hay tres errores:

1. `bindParam()` no es un método del objeto que representa la conexión (`$pdo` en tu caso), sino del objeto que representa la consulta preparada (`$stmt` en tu caso).
2. En esta línea `$stmt = $pdo->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` tú estarías estableciendo el `$stmt` a otra cosa distinta (debido al signo de `=` que se usa para asignación en PHP). Una vez creado `$stmt` con el método `prepare` tienes un objeto y debes usarlo para ir llamando los diferentes métodos de que dispone dicho objeto.
3. Dado que los datos de las consultas se obtienen en forma de recurso, cuando son varios datos deberías colocar el método `fetch` dentro del `while`. Si se espera un solo dato puedes usar directamente `fetchColumn()`

Así debería funcionar:

```
if($pdo) {
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $theID = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    #Prueba
    var_dump($theID);  
}
```

En el código anterior parecería que sólo interesa el `id` y que se espera una sola fila. Por eso escribimos un SELECT específico y usamos `fetchColumn()`. En caso de que se necesiten varias filas veamos un ejemplo de cómo debes mover los resultados dentro del `while`:

```
if($pdo) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $arr = array();
    #El puntero se mueve dentro del bucle
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        #Cada fila se irá guardando en $arr
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    #Prueba
    var_dump($arr);  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

el error que te aparece parece es por un error de la librería PDO al conectar con la base de datos. Puedes utilizar este código para conectar con la BD MySQL, que lo tome de Oscar Abad Folgueira: http://www.oscarabadfolgueira.com:

```
<?php
    
    // Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "1234";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "nombreDB";
    
  
    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
    
    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );

    // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM nombreTabla";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
    
    // Motrar el resultado de los registro de la base de datos
    // Encabezado de la tabla
    echo "<table borde='2px'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Campo1</th>";
    echo "<th>Campo2</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $columna['Campo1'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['Campo2'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla

    // cerrar conexión de base de datos
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: Pero si en ese código no usas ningún objeto PDO. Las trazas aportadas dejan claro que no es un error de conexión: "Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()".

Comment: Yo intente concetar con PDO pero me aparecía un error semejante, lo que encontré es que el servidor web no reconoce esta libreria porque me imagino que se la debe instalar o llamar de algún modo, por eso menciona "Call to undefined method PDO"; si alguno sabe cómo instalarla, o cómo funciona sería magnifico.